# If problem A reduces to an NP-Complete problem B, can we say that A is in NP?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np

I was reviewing [All NP problems reduce to NP-complete problems: so how can NP problems not be NP-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/all-np-problems-reduce-to-np-complete-problems-so-how-can-np-problems-not-be-np)

I understand that the general way we show a problem A is in NP is to show there exists a poly-time certifier for A. However, I am confused if say, we know nothing about A, and it reduces to an NP-Complete problem B, can we now say that A is in NP?

I understand that all problems in NP reduce to any NP-Complete problems, but I'm not sure if this will prove anything. I also understand to show a problem is NP-Complete, we first show it's in NP with a poly-time verifier/certificate and then reduce an NP-Complete problem to it. But confused about this other scenario:

Let A be an unknown problem.
Let B be a known problem in NP-Complete.
A reduces to B
What does this tell us about A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (assuming you meant poly-time reductions).

Being in $NP-complete$ is equivalent to being in both classes:

1. NP
2. NP-hard

In particular, $B\in NP$. Now, $A\in NP$ since $A\le_p B$ and $NP$ is closed under poly-time reductions (you can easily see how to create a non-deterministic poly-time TM for $A$ given the reduction $f$ and a TM for $B$)